# docker-py exec_start howto stream the output to stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, dockerpy

I'm trying to execute some long processes with docker-py
My problem is that I'm not able to see the output of what I'm doing...

How can I stream the output from the docker exec directly to stdout ? or better to logging ?

I've seen there is a "stream" parameter, but I don't undestand how to use the generator returned...

```
        exec_c=self.docker.exec_create(myContainer,e["cmd"])
        output=self.docker.exec_start(exec_c)
        self.logger.info(output)
```

http://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=exec#exec_create

Answer (score 6):

Example of how you can get stdout output. Stdout for default is true o complet stdout=true

Here's python code:

```
from docker import Client
cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')

id_container = '14484253f0a8'
cli.start(id_container)
cmds='ls' #comand to execute

exe = cli.exec_create(container=id_container, cmd=cmds)
exe_start= cli.exec_start(exec_id=exe, stream=True)

for val in exe_start:
    print (val)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use in order to get responses from build commands. You should be able to adapt this code to exec_start needs.

Create a StreamLineBuilder generator:

```
import json
class StreamLineBuildGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, json_data):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(json_data)
```

And then use this generator in order to parse your stream:

```
import docker
docker_client = docker.Client(version="1.18", base_url="unix:///var/run/docker.sock")

generator = docker_client.build(nocache=False, rm=True, stream=True, tag="my_image_tag", path="my_path")

for line in generator:
    try:
        stream_line = StreamLineBuildGenerator(line)
        # Do something with your stream line
        # ...
    except ValueError:
        # If we are not able to deserialize the received line as JSON object, just print it out
        print(line)
        continue
```

Comment: ```stream=True``` has since been deprecated and does not do anything anymore. You'd have to use the low level api now. See also https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/models/images.py#L168